# Time-lagged Pearson Correlation Coefficient

Tags: correlation, time-series

I am a bit confused about the relation between the Pearson Correlation Coefficient (with time-lag) and Cross-Correlation. I used to think that Cross-Correlation IS the Pearson Correlation Coefficient with time-lag. I know that's wrong now, but I'm still a bit confused about the topic.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalization), the Pearson Correlation Coefficient with time-lag is the same thing as the normalized Cross-Correlation. Is that correct? Is that the same thing as the Cross-Correlation Coefficient?

And finally, can you recommend any citable sources which explain the normalized cross-correlation?

I'm grateful for any explanations!